# Decoding IntPtr to MultiString

Tags: c#, marshalling

I need to extract the environment strings from a call to `CreateEnvironmentBlock( out IntPtr lpEnvironment, IntPtr hToken, bool bInherit )`, so as to put them in dictionary based on the variable name and its value.

> When this function returns, `lpEnvironment` receives a pointer to the
>   new environment block. The environment block is an array of
>   null-terminated Unicode strings. The list ends with two nulls
>   (`\0\0`).

I cannot easily use `Marshal.Copy` as I do not know the block's length. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to move along it or determine what to copy to something I can then convert more easily. One thought was to pass the `out IntPtr lpEnvironment` as `out char [] lpEnvironment`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The .NET marshalling system is not aware of this (hideous) multi-string format. You'll have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Use `Marshal.ReadInt16 (IntPtr)` method. Read unicode characters until two 0 values are read. Increment IntPtr returned by CreateEnvironmentBlock by two on every iteration. `out IntPtr` declaration is OK. Don't forget to call  `DestroyEnvironmentBlock`.

Comment: How is this different then using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables()`?

Comment: @MariusBancila - by hToken parameter, probably OP needs it for Windows Service.

Comment: Yes I am running under a spooler service so not under the user account, yet need the user variables, so have to do an impersonation.

Answer (score 4):

You dont know the whole length for `Marshal.Copy()`, however you know the length of the first string if you perform `Marshal.PtrToString()`. With that knowledge you can advance to the next string and so on, until you read an empty string, that indicates only `\0` was present at that address, which is the end of the multi string.

Note that the following code assumes Unicode charset is available and uses it.

```
[DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref IntPtr lpEnvironment,IntPtr hToken,bool bInherit);

static IEnumerable<string> ExtractMultiString(IntPtr ptr)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string str = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr);
        if (str.Length == 0)
            break;
        yield return str;
        ptr = new IntPtr(ptr.ToInt64() + (str.Length + 1 /* char \0 */) * sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

Comment: A version that returns `IEnumerable<string>` using `yield return` might be nice.